# Timing of New Changes in Change Sets

Tags: change-set

Scenario:

1. Change Set is created
2. A Custom Link (labeled type "Button or Link") is added to the Change Set
3. The Custom Link is changed in the Setup menu, specifically, the URL used
4. The Change Set is uploaded to the Target org

Will the changes that occurred in step #3 be deployed in the Target org? Or will the current "state" of the Custom Link when it is first added to Change Set (step #2) be what is deployed to the Target org?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will the changes that occurred in step #3 be deployed in the Target org?

Yes. The contents of the Change Set are not locked in until the point when it is uploaded.

Once the Change Set has been uploaded, new alterations to the metadata contained in the Change Set don't propagate to the target org. At that point, you need to clone the Change Set. You can then upload the clone to pick up the current state of all of its contents in the source org.